# Element goes out of DIV

Tags: html, css

I am getting very annoyed because I cannot figure out where the problem with the styling is. My `btnBox` div keeps going outside of the `noteBoxes` div, I have messed around with it for more than an hour and still cannot solve the problem, don't worry about the js, sorry bout that. I just need help putting the `btnBox` div inside the `noteBoxes` div and to the right of the textarea. Any help is appreciated.

```css
/* textarea styling for notes */

.notesE {
  width: 478px;
  max-width: 478px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  clear: both;
}

.btnBox {
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  width: 11px;
  clear: both;
  top: 0px;
}


/* remove note button */

.removeNote {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #fc7979;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.saveNote {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #46e68b;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear: both;
}


/* div that holds note and button and date */

.noteBoxes {
  width: 510px;
  height: 128px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.dateTxt {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="custNotes" style="width: 550px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <h3>
    <!-- Customer Value-->Notes</h3>
  <button class="options" onclick="addNote()" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">add</button>


  <p id="Message"></p>
  <div class="notesScroll" style="width: 550px; background-color: #606060; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id="notesBox" style="padding: 10px; width: 510px;">
      <!-- <div class="btnBox" style="width: 10px; height: 100px;">
        <button class="saveNote"></button>
        <button class="removeNote" style="margin-top: -4px; margin-left: 0;"></button>
      </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Set #notesBox{
overflow:hidden;
} and then adjust the height of your button as well as the notebox.

Comment: Why is #btnBox commented out?

Comment: The #btnBox does stay within #noteBox. What text area are you referring to? Probably "Message"?

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have a default height set on noteboxes, so when the button box renders it renders beyond the default height.  If you remove the default height the noteboxes will stretch to contain the buttonboxes.  Is that what you are looking for?

```js
var noteCount = 0;

function addNote(style) {

  const notesBox = document.getElementById('notesBox');
  var noteBoxes = document.createElement('div');
  textarea = document.createElement('textarea'),
    btnBox = document.createElement('div'),
    save = document.createElement('button'),
    remove = document.createElement('button'),
    today = new Date();

  var txtElement = document.createElement('p');
  var dateString = '' + today.toLocaleDateString() + ' ' + today.getHours() + ':' + today.getMinutes();
  txtElement.innerHTML = dateString;
  txtElement.setAttribute('class', style);
  txtElement.className = 'dateTxt';
  txtElement.setAttribute('id', style);
  txtElement.id = 'note ' + noteCount + ' date';
  txtElement.setAttribute('data-month', today.getMonth() + 1);
  txtElement.setAttribute('data-year', today.getFullYear());
  // div that holds each note and remove button and date
  notesBox.appendChild(noteBoxes);
  noteBoxes.setAttribute('class', style);
  noteBoxes.className = 'noteBoxes';
  noteBoxes.setAttribute('id', style);
  noteBoxes.id = 'note box ' + noteCount;
  noteBoxes.appendChild(txtElement);
  noteBoxes.appendChild(textarea);
  noteBoxes.appendChild(btnBox);

  // note that is added
  textarea.setAttribute('class', style);
  textarea.className = 'notesE';
  textarea.setAttribute('id', style);
  textarea.id = 'note' + noteCount;

  // button box
  btnBox.setAttribute('class', style);
  btnBox.className = 'btnBox';
  btnBox.setAttribute('id', style);
  btnBox.id = 'btnBox' + noteCount;
  btnBox.appendChild(save);
  btnBox.appendChild(remove);

  // save button
  save.setAttribute('title', style);
  save.title = 'save';
  save.setAttribute('class', style);
  save.className = 'saveNote';
  save.setAttribute('id', style);
  save.id = '+Note' + noteCount;

  // button to remove note
  remove.setAttribute('title', style);
  remove.title = 'delete';
  remove.setAttribute('class', style);
  remove.className = 'removeNote';
  remove.setAttribute('id', style);
  remove.id = '-Note' + noteCount;
  remove.onclick = function() {
    // confirm alert dialog
    // deletes the note if user selects 'OK'
    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this note?") == true) {
      // removes the noteBoxes div of which the button clicked is in.
      this.parentElement.remove();
    }
  }
  noteCount++;
  console.log(textarea.id);


  var month = document.getElementById('selectMonth');
  var year = document.getElementById('selectYear');
  var searchDate = document.getElementById('searchDate');




}
```

```css
/* textarea styling for notes */

.notesE {
  width: 478px;
  max-width: 478px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  clear: both;
}

.btnBox {
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  width: 11px;
  clear: both;
  top: 0px;
}


/* remove note button */

.removeNote {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #fc7979;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.saveNote {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #46e68b;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear: both;
}


/* div that holds note and button and date */

.noteBoxes {
  width: 510px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.dateTxt {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="custNotes" style="width: 550px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <h3>
    <!-- Customer Value-->Notes</h3>
  <button class="options" onclick="addNote()" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">add</button>


  <p id="Message"></p>
  <div class="notesScroll" style="width: 550px; background-color: #606060; margin: 0 auto;">
    <div id="notesBox" style="padding: 10px; width: 510px;">
      <!-- <div class="btnBox" style="width: 10px; height: 100px;">
        <button class="saveNote"></button>
        <button class="removeNote" style="margin-top: -4px; margin-left: 0;"></button>
      </div> -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have to guess at the question then your answer can only be a guess which makes this question off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. Not all questions need to be answered. Only answer well-asked questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want a text-area and those two buttons on the right side of the text-area. Check the following changes ->

```css
/* textarea styling for notes */

.notesE {
  width: 478px;
  max-width: 478px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: none;
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: none;
  clear: both;
}

.btnBox {
  height: 100px;
  border: none;
  width: 11px;
  clear: both;
  top: 0px;
  float:right;
}


/* remove note button */

.removeNote {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #fc7979;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-top: -4px;
  margin-left: 0;
  clear: both;
}

.saveNote {
  width: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
  background-color: #46e68b;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear: both;
}


/* div that holds note and button and date */

.noteBoxes {
  width: 510px;
  height: 128px;
}

.dateTxt {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #ccc;
}

.notesScroll{
  width: 510px; 
  background-color: #606060; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="custNotes" style="width: 550px; margin: 0 auto;">
  <h3>
    <!-- Customer Value-->Notes</h3>
  <button class="options" onclick="addNote()" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">add</button>


  <p id="Message"></p>
  <div class="notesScroll" >
      <div id="notesBox" class= noteBoxes>
        <div class="btnBox" >  
          <button class="saveNote"></button>
          <button class="removeNote" style="margin-top: -4px; margin-left: 0;">        </button>  
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have to guess at the question then your answer can only be a guess which makes this question off topic. Do not answer off topic questions. Not all questions need to be answered. Only answer well-asked questions. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer